# Dispatch extra action on every action using middleware

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

```
export default ({ dispatch, getState }) => next => action => {
  return next(action);
};
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, the above should be the template for creating redux middleware. I'm wondering if it's possible to dispatch an extra action in this middleware? Think of it as a logger function which I'm trying to log all actions that's being dispatched.

Instead of console logging here, I wished to store it into another reducer.

In shorts, the idea is one action flows thru this middleware, 1 original action + 1 logging action both being dispatched

Comment: Why do you want to create an extra action? You can create a logging reducer, you can process every original action here without making extra.

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs: Just trying to have a better picture on how to manipulate with Middleware. I do aware that create extra logging reducer can achieve the same objective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I get your question `if it's possible to dispatch an extra action in this middleware?` but you can dispatch as many actions as you want, something like that:

```
export const getBooks = ({dispatch}) => next => action => {
  next(action);
  if (action.type === 'GET_BOOKS') {
    dispatch({type:'API_REQUEST', payload:'yourUrl'});
  }
  if (action.type === 'SOMETHING_ELSE') dispatch(anotherAction());
};
```

Then you could add a another middleware to observe the actions dispatched by this one i.e.

```
export const api = ({dispatch}) => next => action => {

  if(action.type === 'API_REQUEST') {
    const { url } = action.payload;

    fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => dispatch({ type: 'onSuccess', payload: data }))
      .catch(error => dispatch({ type: 'onError', payload: error }))
  }
  return next(action)
};
```

Obviously, at your store, the first one need to preceed the second one, i.e.

```
const middlewares = [getBooks, api];
const store = createStore(yourReducer,applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```